# Are GUIDs the ultimate ID?

Tags: guid

I noticed some people don't bother having the usual incremented number as ID but instead simply generate a GUID. The advantages include:

- Quick and easy
- No need to keep track of previous IDs
- Guaranteed to be unique even across machines without knowledge of each other

Some disadvantages are:

- Possibly performance bottleneck
- Uses a large number of bytes

My understanding is that using a GUID is beneficial in most cases, except if optimization for time or space is an issue. Did I miss something? Or do you agree with this idea?

Comment: not guaranteed to be unique, just very probable

Comment: Indeed not guaranteed, but extremely unlikely as far as I know.

Comment: @fearofawhackplanet, @mafutrct: See this great answer on uniqueness of the various GUID algorithms: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/703035/when-are-you-truly-forced-to-use-uuid-as-part-of-the-design/786541#786541

Comment: Similar questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/829284/guid-vs-int-identity, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151625/int-vs-unique-identifier-for-id-field-in-database, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171201/sql-server-guid-vs-long

Comment: I think the proposed dup is database specific does not go into detail. This questions deals with using GUIDs in the general case rather than databases.

Comment: due to birthday paradox, if you generate around trilion GUIDs, there is 1% chance that you hit at least one duplicate. still unlikely but not as unlikely as some websites seem to teach on the internet.

Comment: 10^18 (http://www.google.com/search?q=(-2+*+(2^128)*+ln(0.99))+^+0.5)  but keep in mind that GUID generators are not evenly using all bits. in theory it's 10^18 but in practice could be 10^12... there are reports on the internet from people who claim to hit duplicates. it's still rare but certainly not unbelievable.

Comment: I added a separate question on that topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757910/how-are-net-4-guids-generated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of cons:

- Pain in the neck if you have to delve into anything manually (debuggin etc).  They are completely unreadable.
- Horrible if you ever need to pass them in a URL