# primary key datatype in sql server database

Tags: sql, sql-server, primary-key, uniqueidentifier

i see after installing the asp.net membership tables, they use the data type "uniqueidentifier" for all of the primary key fields.

I have been using "int" data type and doing increment by one on inserts and declaring the column as IDENTITY.

Is there any particular benefits to using the uniqueIdentifier data type compared to my current model of using int and auto increments on new inserts ?

Comment: What clustered indexes do you have on your tables? If you are clustering by Id field then the sequential int will cause fewer page splits on inserts than GUID and newid() will.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it better to use an uniqueidentifier(GUID) or a bigint for an identity column?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/504905/is-it-better-to-use-an-uniqueidentifierguid-or-a-bigint-for-an-identity-column) (and many others too numerous to mention)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally use INT IDENTITY for most of my primary and clustering keys. I think it's rather unfortunate that Microsoft chose to use `Uniqueidentifier` in their ASP.NET membership tables - lots of people take that database as a "template" for other.....

You need to keep apart the **primary key** which is a logical construct - it uniquely identifies your rows, it has to be unique and stable and NOT NULL. A GUID works well for a primary key, too - since it's guaranteed to be unique. A GUID as your primary key is a good choice if you use SQL Server replication, since in that case, you need an uniquely identifying GUID column anyway.

The **clustering key** in SQL Server is a physical construct is used for the physical ordering of the data, and is a lot more difficult to get right. Typically, the Queen of Indexing on SQL Server, Kimberly Tripp, also requires a good clustering key to be unique, stable, as narrow as possible, and ideally ever-increasing (which a INT IDENTITY is).

See her articles on indexing here:

- [GUIDs as PRIMARY KEYs and/or the clustering key](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/GUIDs-as-PRIMARY-KEYs-andor-the-clustering-key.aspx)
- [The Clustered Index Debate Continues...](http://sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/The-Clustered-Index-Debate-Continues.aspx)
- [Ever-increasing clustering key - the Clustered Index Debate..........again!](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/Ever-increasing-clustering-key-the-Clustered-Index-Debateagain!.aspx)

and also see Jimmy Nilsson's [The Cost of GUIDs as Primary Key](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=25862)

A GUID is a really bad choice for a clustering key, since it's wide, totally random, and thus leads to bad index fragmentation and poor performance. Also, the clustering key row(s) is also stored in each and every entry of each and every non-clustered (additional) index, so you really want to keep it small - GUID is 16 byte vs. INT is 4 byte, and with several non-clustered indices and several million rows, this makes a HUGE difference.

In SQL Server, your primary key is by default your clustering key - but it doesn't have to be. You can easily use a GUID as your NON-Clustered primary key, and an INT IDENTITY as your clustering key - it just takes a bit of being aware of it.

Answer (score 2):

`uniqueidenfitier` solves problems with replication. It's possible for two replicated versions of a table to insert rows with the same integer value for the key, but it's impossible for them to both insert using the same `uniqueidentifier`, assuming the value of the column is set to `newid`.

Comment: Me too. I don't see a reason for anything more than a comment. Instead, we get the downvote instead of a comment.

Answer (score 1):

> I have been using "int" data type and doing increment by one on inserts.

In SQL Server the way to get an auto incrementing column is to use [`IDENTITY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933196.aspx). I'm not sure if that is what you meant by the above so I thought I would clarify this just in case.

The advantage of using an `INT` column with `IDENTITY` is that it is smaller so joins will be slightly faster. But for most purposes it won't be a significant improvement. There are other things you should worry about first, like choosing the correct indexes for your tables.

Comment: Joins do factor into it slightly, but page splits for clustered indexes are generally the more important reason for using an auto-incrementing key (or sequential GUID).  Since a user table probably doesn't have to handle too many insertions, GUIDs are usually OK.

Comment: @Aaronaught: True, +1 for bringing it up as it is worth considering, but note that the primary and clustered keys can be different. If this is the case this point becomes irrelevant. Note also that the space issue is also a serious consideration when choosing a clustered index as every index includes a copy of the clustered key. This will reduce the number of index entries that can be stored per page.

Comment: @MarkByers your link appears to be slightly less useful than it perhaps once was.